# What QuickBooks SDK 13.0 namespace is required to instantiate QBSessionManager?

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have downloaded QuickBooks SDK 13.0 and am trying to build a very simple C# application that connects to `QuickBooks` via `QBSessionManager`.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013.  I have the following lines of code in the Load function of my very simple Form.

```
QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "Application");
```

When I try to compile, I get

> The type or namespace name 'QBSessionManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I see lots of sample code that starts with instantiating `QBSessionManager`, but nothing that identifes the namespace or reference I need to specify.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: have you installed the SDK?

Comment: I added "using QBFC13Lib;" to my code and added a reference to qbFC13 1.0 Type Library in Visual Studio (PROJECT->Add Reference).  Then it compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Add the file QBFC13Lib.dll to your project requirements.

The file can be found in the c:Program Files(x86)\Common Files\intuit\QuickBooks directory of a standard install of quickbooks.

Comment: Because I didn't have QuickBooks installed, I installed the SDK at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/quickbooks_desktop/download_the_sdk